# R - Matching date with a matrix row

Tags: r, matrix, matching

first I apologize if the title it's not the correct one so if someone know of a more appropriate one I would appreciate.
So I have the following data

```
set.seed(10)
data <- array(rexp(10*15*6), dim=c(150,6))

time <- seq(as.Date('1980-01-01'),as.Date('1980-06-01'), by='month')
```

Here data represents 150 observations in 6 months, and I want to match all 150 observations for each date

I want to obtain something like this:

```
                   [,1]         [,2]          [,3]          [,4]  ...[,150]         
1980-01-01  0.369566293  1.810335935  0.803660761   1.002360356 
1980-02-01  1.256060787  1.251835328  0.101172015   0.686529982 
1980-03-01  1.994590582  0.306240226  0.785003196   1.720532145 
.
.
.
1980-06-01
```

Comment: How do you want match the observations? Do you mean `new_data <- t(data)
row.names(new_data) <- as.character(time)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but if you'd like to create a time-series object I recommend using `zoo`:

```
library(zoo);
tseries <- zoo(t(data), time)
```

This creates a `zoo` time series of dimension

```
dim(tseries);
#[1]   6 150
```